# Expose a method or property in application to be consumed by others VB6

Tags: windows, com, vb6

I will try to explain this problem to the best of my abilities. I have a VB6 application (call it APP1) that consumes a DLL, which in turns communicates with a COM port (probably irrelevant). The issue with the DLL(probably because of the com port) that it can be consumed only by one application at a time. I am running another application (APP2) that wants to get a status reading from APP1 on that comm port, at any time. Both apps are running independently. **Is there a way to expose something out of APP1 so I can read it real time in APP2**? Again, my limitation is that both apps are written in VB6, and currently I have no resources to re-write them.

Thank you.

Comment: You could do this via socket communication.  Host a socket server in app 1 and call it with app 2.

Comment: Create an ActiveX Exe